# Django, Bootstrap responsive text area

Tags: javascript, django-views, bootstrap-5

I Wrote a little java script to make a text area responsive, depending on the image size next to it. That works pretty fine except of a weired random bug I really don't understand. This is how the page should look like:

[image]

That works in approx. 70% on the time, that the textarea is loaded with the correct hight. Every once and a while it happens that this happens:

[image]

If I refresh the page it directly takes the correct hight. Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3 text-center">Willkommen auf</h1>
        <h1 class="display-6 text-center">Diese Seite befindet sich im Aufbau</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-3">
                <div id="targetcard" class="card">
                    <img id="pic_uc" class="nav-item rounded" src="https://placehold.co/600x400"
                        alt=""></img>
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.freepik.com"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text fs-6 fw-light lh-1">Designed by BiZkettE1 / Freepik</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-3">
            <div id="textContentAre" class="card border-0 overflow-y-scroll">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur officiis iusto dolorum aspernatur
                    itaque sunt placeat veniam velit eius! Itaque molestias laborum repellat dicta doloribus? Unde atque
                    perferendis eaque architecto. Tempora sapiente accusantium iste libero qui fugiat consectetur laudantium
                    placeat ab explicabo inventore sunt modi facere a dolor, vitae at ratione! Explicabo nulla quasi
                    provident facilis repellendus esse deleniti tenetur eaque ratione perferendis sunt rerum amet
                    accusantium hic
                    temporibus quidem, laborum nemo blanditiis doloremque! Fugit eligendi atque illo. Molestiae modi ex
                    magnam id quaerat perferendis laboriosam illo repellat, in reiciendis! Rem voluptate quae fugit
                    doloremque
                    molestias unde ab necessitatibus perspiciatis, ipsa autem, voluptas commodi esse ex. Incidunt libero
                    dolores consequuntur distinctio sequi impedit voluptatibus, eum inventore, deserunt facere quidem error,
                    minima
                    sunt labore enim? Recusandae labore dignissimos libero ab asperiores maiores tenetur magnam, rerum
                    itaque
                    voluptate ipsa dolorum voluptatem officia in alias omnis! Animi incidunt, ipsa molestias a ut ducimus
                    consequuntur libero dicta expedita voluptatem fuga nam veniam facere ad pariatur voluptate autem sunt
                    reiciendis reprehenderit maiores. Nostrum, architecto. Veniam id facere suscipit aliquid vitae
                    consequuntur eum aspernatur quam magnam libero illo voluptate corporis iste pariatur consequatur, totam
                    eligendi
                    eveniet adipisci obcaecati qui architecto incidunt molestias mollitia fugiat. Laborum quod, sunt
                    perspiciatis
                    minima totam architecto quibusdam! Eligendi dignissimos eos ut? Maxime distinctio repellat non magnam
                    cupiditate beatae corrupti laboriosam deserunt quisquam ullam quam assumenda itaque dolores debitis
                    facere
                    exercitationem, officiis explicabo doloribus nobis. Error quibusdam ut suscipit in a. Nisi ad doloremque
                    ipsum sit tempore perferendis reiciendis accusamus tenetur facilis cupiditate molestias est autem ea
                    vero nostrum ipsa magnam, iste ipsam deserunt rem fugit. Quidem magnam recusandae doloribus dignissimos
                    ad
                    modi inventore sint labore saepe! Tenetur, neque hic ducimus quaerat odit maiores officiis nostrum
                    aliquid,
                    architecto ut perspiciatis qui adipisci quas. Ab, laudantium ratione. Cupiditate consequatur iure.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col my-3 text-center">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    Kontakt <a href="#" class="text-reset">Kontakt</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            let height = document.querySelector("#targetcard").clientHeight;
            document.querySelector('#textContentAre').style.height = height + "px";
            window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
                //console.log('View Port: ' + window.innerWidth)
                if (height != document.querySelector("#targetcard").clientHeight) {
                    height = document.querySelector("#targetcard").clientHeight;
                    document.querySelector('#textContentAre').style.height = height + "px";
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    </script>
</div>
```

If someone could tell me why the textare sometimes is loaded with the wrong hight I would be really thankful.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` does not wait for images to load, so most likely you are simply trying to read the image dimensions before they are available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That sounds very logical. Do you have any idea how I can make sure that the size is not read out too early? I can't think of anything about how to do that, especially since I assumed that DOMContentLoaded was just waiting for the DOM to be completely built. I'm an absolute novice in JavaScript, this is my first script that I've written, so I'm not very familiar with the possibilities.

Comment: As you can read here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event, the `load` event would be the alternative, if you want to wait until _all_ external resources, including images, are loaded.

Comment: (I would perhaps rather go for a solution that doesn't use JavaScript in the first place here; by absolutely positioning the text element.)

Comment: Good news i guess I found the solution based on your hint. Since i have to set a max hight for the overflow-y-scroll to work correct I need to get the hight some how. The image is already responsible by Bootstrap but the overflow inside the card isn't. If I dont set the max hight manually the behaviour gets really scarry. If I would see a solution to get along without java script, that also would be my preffered choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without any JavaScript.

Two `col` elements that display next to each other already automatically *have* the same height, due to the fact that Bootstrap 5 uses flexbox for its grid system.

So all we need to do here, is resolve the conflict that both of those columns are "competing" about which of them is the larger one, that will determine the height of the whole row.

By positioning the text element inside its column absolute, we can achieve that - the text gets taken out of the layout flow, does *not* influence how high the whole row gets any more, that is solely down to the image now.

And if we position the text element *at* all four "corners" of the column element it is in, it will automatically take that width & height. (`inset` sets the values for `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` all in one go.)

The column itself gets `position: relative` to be the anchor point, and for the text element I used `inset: 0 12px`, to replicate the 12px padding-left and -right the column would normally apply to its content.

You will have to check the rendered snippet here in full-screen mode, so that the two-column layout actually applies; and you will also have to wrap this into appropriate media queries, so that my changes *don't* apply below the chosen two-column breakpoint, because there the absolute positioning of the text will mess things up, so it must not be applied there to begin with.

```css
.scrollTextColumn {
  position: relative;
}

#textContentAre {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="display-3 text-center">Willkommen auf</h1>
  <h1 class="display-6 text-center">Diese Seite befindet sich im Aufbau</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-3">
      <div id="targetcard" class="card">
        <img id="pic_uc" class="nav-item rounded" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.freepik.com"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text fs-6 fw-light lh-1">Designed by BiZkettE1 / Freepik</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-3 scrollTextColumn">
      <div id="textContentAre" class="card border-0 overflow-y-scroll">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur officiis iusto dolorum aspernatur itaque sunt placeat veniam velit eius! Itaque molestias laborum repellat dicta doloribus? Unde atque perferendis eaque architecto. Tempora sapiente
        accusantium iste libero qui fugiat consectetur laudantium placeat ab explicabo inventore sunt modi facere a dolor, vitae at ratione! Explicabo nulla quasi provident facilis repellendus esse deleniti tenetur eaque ratione perferendis sunt rerum
        amet accusantium hic temporibus quidem, laborum nemo blanditiis doloremque! Fugit eligendi atque illo. Molestiae modi ex magnam id quaerat perferendis laboriosam illo repellat, in reiciendis! Rem voluptate quae fugit doloremque molestias unde
        ab necessitatibus perspiciatis, ipsa autem, voluptas commodi esse ex. Incidunt libero dolores consequuntur distinctio sequi impedit voluptatibus, eum inventore, deserunt facere quidem error, minima sunt labore enim? Recusandae labore dignissimos
        libero ab asperiores maiores tenetur magnam, rerum itaque voluptate ipsa dolorum voluptatem officia in alias omnis! Animi incidunt, ipsa molestias a ut ducimus consequuntur libero dicta expedita voluptatem fuga nam veniam facere ad pariatur voluptate
        autem sunt reiciendis reprehenderit maiores. Nostrum, architecto. Veniam id facere suscipit aliquid vitae consequuntur eum aspernatur quam magnam libero illo voluptate corporis iste pariatur consequatur, totam eligendi eveniet adipisci obcaecati
        qui architecto incidunt molestias mollitia fugiat. Laborum quod, sunt perspiciatis minima totam architecto quibusdam! Eligendi dignissimos eos ut? Maxime distinctio repellat non magnam cupiditate beatae corrupti laboriosam deserunt quisquam ullam
        quam assumenda itaque dolores debitis facere exercitationem, officiis explicabo doloribus nobis. Error quibusdam ut suscipit in a. Nisi ad doloremque ipsum sit tempore perferendis reiciendis accusamus tenetur facilis cupiditate molestias est autem
        ea vero nostrum ipsa magnam, iste ipsam deserunt rem fugit. Quidem magnam recusandae doloribus dignissimos ad modi inventore sint labore saepe! Tenetur, neque hic ducimus quaerat odit maiores officiis nostrum aliquid, architecto ut perspiciatis
        qui adipisci quas. Ab, laudantium ratione. Cupiditate consequatur iure.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col my-3 text-center">
      <p class="text-muted">
        Kontakt <a href="#" class="text-reset">Kontakt</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your support. As explained, I wrote a mediaquery that hides the `position: absolute;` element as soon as the view port changes from `col-lg` to `col-md`. Unfortunately, the overflow function of the text box then disappears again. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. Of course there will be no scrollbar, if the height of that element is not limited to one less than the content height, by _something_. Can't tell what exactly you did based on that vague description.

Comment: I wanted to keep the hight of the textbox bound to the hight of the image. Regardless of whether the elements are arranged side by side or one above the other.

Comment: For the "one above the other" case, that is not possible that way. If the elements are not _next_ to each other, then this method won't work. All you can do then, if you know the aspect ratio of your image, is to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio on the text element.